# precision of a sum of double in jvm

Tags: java, scala, jvm, double, precision

I have tests that assert that a sum of values is equal to some expected results. These sum are not exactly the value, so I need to put a precision. This is logical as `sum([a, a, a, ...n-times..., a]) != n*a`.

But instead of putting an arbitrary precision, I would like to know the expected bound. How can I compute such a bound?

In the specific case that lead to my question, I sum n zeros and k ones (which are obtained by computing difference of doubles, v1-v2). This should thus be equals to k +- precision.

So what precision should be used?

- k * 10e-15
- (n+k) * 10e-15

I guess the 10e-15 also depends on the values added: 0 and 1 here

Comment: I’d take the wider of the two, just in case, or maybe something even wider. I suspect the test is there two catch errors where too few or two many 1s go into the addition, so a precision of 0.5 would work. Not that I’d pick that, but it shows that it hardly important which of your suggestions you pick.

Comment: I was not clear enough: the tested values *should be* 0s and 1s. but they could be 0 or 1 + 10e-10 (or anything else). That would be an error that I would like to catch. I know that by design there is a limite to the precision of such a test, but I'd like to know the best precision I can require.